# Erro: Array to string conversion - Select multiple Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5

Na minha View tenho:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="carga_mental[]" class="form-control select2">
    @foreach($cadastros->where('key', 'carga_mental') as $carga_mental)
        <option value="{{ $carga_mental->title }}"> {{ $carga_mental->title }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

No meu Controller tenho:

```
$this->repository->update($request->all(), $id);
```

Quando faço o envio do formulário retorna esse erro:

> Array to string conversion (SQL: update `relatorio_setores` set
>   `carga_mental` = Condições Confortáveis, where `id` = 4)

E ele só pega o primeiro item selecionado.

Minha intenção é gravar os itens selecionados na tabela no formato JSON, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: o seu banco aceita `json` nativo, ou seja, já é a versão do MySQL que possui um campo `json`?

Comment: Não sei dizer @VirgilioNovic, achei que era só jogar num campo tipo text

Comment: Tem uma forma de trabalhar se quiser eu posta uma proposta! mas, também `$this->repository` que esta ferrando um pouco o que tem dentro disso

Answer (score 0):

Na maneira que enviou diretamente, sem converter o dado vai dar erro mesmo, precisa antes converter com [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php), para enviar um texto no formato [json](/questions/tagged/json) para a tabela no banco. No `MySQL` a [partir da versão 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) já existe um campo responsável em gravar dados no formato [json](/questions/tagged/json) e o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) utilizado no `Laravel` já faz isso. Mas pelo visto precisa fazer da maneira tradicional gravando em um tabela em algum campo [`varchar`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html).

Como seria basicamente pelo seu código:

```
// pegando todos menos carga_mental
$data = $request->except('carga_mental'); 

//criando a chave carga_mental com um texto no formato json
$data['carga_mental'] = json_encode($request->input('carga_mental'));

//atualizando ...
$this->repository->update($data, $id);
```

ou seja, a conversão deve ser feita antes de enviar para a **rotina/método** que **grava** ou **atualiza** suas informações.

Só lembrando que para utilizar esse campo no formato `array` precisa ser convertido com [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).

**Referencias:**

- [json-encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)
- [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)
- [12.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)
- [12.4.1 The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html)